# Homebrew uninstalling fails

Tags: macos, applescript, command-line, homebrew

I am trying to uninstall a cask using homebrew, but each time it fails due to (I believe) AppleScript failing to run. I believe this issue stems from my multiuser setup (I am a non admin).

```
Error: Failure while executing; `osascript -e tell\ application\ \"System\ Events\"\ to\ delete\ every\ login\ item\ whose\ name\ is\ \"CleanMyMac\ 4\ Menu\"` exited with 1. Here's the output:
36:93: execution error: System Events got an error: AppleEvent timed out. (-1712)
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I am just trying to remove a cask from my computer and not have homebrew still think it is installed and try to update it every blue moon. If I have to remove it manually and update homebrew manually, so be it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-cask/issues/50413

The solution was described as going to:
/usr/local/Caskroom/CASKNAME/.metadata/CASKVERSION/WEIRDIDENTIFIER/Casks/CASKNAME.rb

And then from there I can remove the line that attempts to remove the login item. Then it uninstalls successfully and I can manually remove the login item.

Answer (score 0):

It appears that this app is running on startup.  In order to remove that (or install it) you have to be an admin.  Before uninstalling anything in a multiuser environment, it's a good idea to check with the other users and make sure someone is not using the program.  And asking the admin is a great place to ask for help/permission to remove the program.

Comment: I am the admin, I revoke admin permissions from myself. And when trying to uninstall this, I have to run homebrew as my privileged user, which I access via terminal.

Comment: I thought one of the main things for Homebrew is that it runs for a normal user

Comment: It can, if you have administrator access. I have revoked this from myself to increase security of my machine.